# how to use a randomized TOKEN to reload PHP script with AJAX, url is being cached?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, token

I have this AJAX call I'm making. How can I make this JQuery refresh/reload the script that is being called and execute the AJAX call afterwards. I want to use this in case the user re-clicks the same button again and show new data.

**Problem:**

How do I include a token? My show_aht.php is being cached

When aht_button is clicked it returns data, but if I refresh the page and/or I reclick the button it will still show me the old data or do nothing at all. I have to manually refresh my "show_aht.php" on my browser and then click on "aht_button" so I can display the new data being retrieve from "show_aht.php".

I did not want to post my PHP code because its a lot of stuff.. maybe someone can find the problem because I have no clue. Not sure if we can reload a PHP script by itself? I've put only the important stuff.

thanks in advance!

JS:

```
<div id="aht">
    <button id="aht_button">AHT</button>    
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#aht').click(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                    type:"GET",
                    url : "show_aht.php", //use a token here??
                    data:{ } ,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success : function(data){
                        //get the MIN value from the array
                            var min = data.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
                                return isNaN(+curr['aht_value']) || prev < +curr['aht_value'] ? prev : +curr['aht_value'];
                            }, 1000000);

                            alert("min:" + min); 
                            //get the MAX value from the array
                            var max = data.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
                              return isNaN(+curr['aht_value']) || prev > +curr['aht_value'] ? prev : +curr['aht_value'];
                            }, -1000000); 

                            alert("max:" + max);
                            //function for calculation of background color depending on aht_value               
                            function conv(x){
                                return Math.floor((x - min) / (max - min) * 255);
                            }

                            //function for background color, if NA then show white background, either show from green to red
                            function colorMe(v){
                              return v == 'NA' ? "#FFF" : "rgb(" + conv(v) + "," + (255-conv(v)) + ",0)";
                            }

                        //going through all DIVs only once with this loop
                        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { // loop over results
                        var divForResult = $('#desk_' + data[i]['station']); // look for div for this object
                        if(divForResult.length) { // if a div was found
                            divForResult.html(data[i]['aht_value']).css("background-color", colorMe(data[i]['aht_value']));
                        }//end if
                        }//end for  
                    }//end success
                });//end ajax   
              });//end click
            });//end rdy
        </script>
```

PHP:

```
include 'db_conn_retca2003.php';
include 'db_conn_retca2001.php';
header('Content-type: application/json');

    /****************************************************
    matching USER array and MEMO array 
    for matching username values
    /****************************************************/
    $result = array();
    foreach ($memo as $username => $memodata) {
    if (in_array($username, array_keys($user))) {
    // Match username against the keys of $user (the usernames) 
    $userdata = $user[$username];
    //if AHT is null give N/A as value
    if (is_null($memodata['aht_value'])) {
        $result[] = array( 'username'  => $userdata['username'],
                                             'aht_value' => 'NA',
                                             'station'  => $userdata['station']
                                            );
    }//end inner if 
    //else give the actual value of AHT without the decimals
    else {
        $result[] = array( 'username'  => $userdata['username'],
                                             'aht_value' => substr($memodata['aht_value'],0,-3),
                                             'station'   => $userdata['station']
                                        );
    }//end else
    }//end outer if
    }//end for
  echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but it sounds like your php is the problem here, not the js.

Comment: @minseong  I will upload my php code then.. but its a lot of stuff...

Comment: Try and cut it down into the important parts - I once got a load of downvotes because I put on too much code.

Comment: how is the data stored? Sounds like your php is hanging on to something in a session perhaps?

Comment: @minseong yes thank you, I posted my code

Comment: @Edward its being stored in an json_encoded array could that be the problem?

Comment: too detailed, repeat your issue with minimal amount of code, and try again

Comment: no that wouldn't cause it, the array should be being re-fetched from your DB every time the script is run, regardless weather that is via ajax or browser, can you run this script without ajax?

Comment: @Edward both scripts are in the same directory. Yes I can run the php script by itself and it will show me the entire array. I have to refresh the php script on the browser and then click on my ajax button to show the new data. its very annoying

Comment: ok so if you can receive the data you need reliably whilst running it without ajax (as your ajax isn't sending params "data {  }") that tells me your php is sound, is this the case?

Comment: @Edward im sorry I didn't understand what you're asking. What do you mean my php is sound? No I am not sending any parameters in my AJAX since I am just retrieving echo json_encode and using GET.. Not sure if I need to send any params in this case

Comment: sorry, by 'sound' I mean that it works as expected?

Comment: @Edward yes my php is working as expect except that I need to refresh the script to see the new array. It gives me new values each time since its querying the database for data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65626/discussion-between-edward-and-alda1234).

Answer (score 0):

you can add in you success:   location.reload();  // refreshes the page automatically

or you can use .on('click',function..) it will show updated results for future elements